# Find the maximum amount of pairs in a list of pairs

Tags: algorithm, python-2.7, graph-theory

I have a list of pairs that I've generated from certain numbers. My question doesn't pertain as to how my pairs are calculated as I have figured that out, but maximizing the total possible number of pairs.
For example:

```
[1,3,7,19,13,21]
```

results in

```
{1:[19,13,21],  
 3:[7,19],  
 7:[3,19,13],  
 19:[1,3,7,21],  
 13:[1,7,21],  
 21:[1,19,13]}
```

1 can pair with 19, 13, or 21. 3 can pair with 7 or 19, and so on. My goal is to maximize the unique pairing such that I have the least amount of points left over without a pair. In this case, you can have 1-13, 3-7, and 19-21, which gives 0 left overs. But you could also do 1-19, 7-13, which leaves 3 and 21 without a partner.

Is there an algorithm that has dealt with this problem before? I thought about putting them into a graph and trying to find the largest Hamiltonian path but that's seeming practically impossible. I'm doing this in python so I have dictionaries and lists that I have been using as containers.

Edit: The conditions for whether a number can be paired is if they form a certain pattern with the pair. Given two numbers x and y, they follow this pattern until x == y or it goes forever. If x < y,
 y = y - x and x = 2 * x. Then it goes again, etc...

Comment: Forgive me it this is a dumb question, but what are the conditions that allow two numbers  to make a pair. For instance in your last example, why can't 3 and 21 a pair?

Comment: I added in an edit that explained the pairing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that you describe is finding the [maximal matching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_(graph_theory)#Maximal_matchings) in a graph (in your example, if `i` is paired with `j` then `j` is also paired with `i`, so you can connect them by an edge). The following [python package](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.9.1/reference/algorithms.matching.html) as well as 
[this code](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/221251-maximum-cardinality-matching-in-general-graphs/) contain relevant implementations.

Comment: Yes! That is what I was looking for, but it seems like the thing I want is the maximum-matching yet the existing package only finds a maximal matching.

Comment: @Mathochist yes indeed in the note they write "The algorithm greedily selects a maximal matching M of the graph G (i.e. no superset of M exists)".  This one seem to claim that it indeed finds the maximal cardinality matching:  http://code.activestate.com/recipes/221251-maximum-cardinality-matching-in-general-graphs/